# iOS iPad Master-Detail controller drill down

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am trying to create an iPad app with a master detail principle, so I am using the `UISplitViewController`. The issue is that I want a different behaviour for the app because sometimes the detail view goes deeper. So I want the detail view to become master view and load a new view as detail. To give you an example lets say I have a `ViewController1`, `ViewController2` and `ViewController3`. When a link from the (master) `ViewController1` is clicked, `ViewController2` (detail) should be shown next to it. Now if the user clicks a link in `ViewController2`, `ViewController1` should disappear `ViewController2` should take its place and `ViewController3` should be shown. What is the best way to do something like this cause I can't do that with a `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: Have you read the documentations? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html or https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=uiviewcontroller

Comment: you didn't read the whole question did you? It doesn't work with the SplitViewController the way I want it

Comment: Of course I did read 'the whole question' before commenting! You need to read documentations and everything is provided there. Check out this one as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I am talking about the iPad so that I can have 2 controllers next to each other on the same screen. The best way is of course to use a splitController but I want a completely different behaviour for the navigation and I am trying to find out what the best solution is

Answer (score 0):

By default, a split view template gives you a navigation controller for both the master and detail sides.  I'd look at creating a `ViewController2B` that uses the same data model as `ViewController2` and then synchronize push/pop so that 1 & 2 switched with 2B & 3 as one operation.

Comment: Thats a solution but lets say I want to implement the solution that I am suggesting without having to synchronise and using the same controller twice. What is the best way to do something like this? With a custom container maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure that would be easier but it would certainly work.  Once you have a custom container controller, you can make the child controller views behave any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I get the issue now. I'm not quite sure if this is helpful at all, but sometimes these custom controls are quite helpful. Have you checked them? They might help you implement the code in your own project or just use them maybe?

1. https://github.com/mdznr/MTZSplitViewController
2. https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController
3. https://github.com/sergik-ru/SMTabbedSplitViewController (Slightly different)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes but they also use the splitController and only the appearance is customised not the navigation. I suppose I'll have to go with a container controller. Thanks though